# Football pygame, need help on timer

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, timer, pygame

I want to make a football game and I want to make it so that the player only gets 10 seconds to get to the end or else the game ends.

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you post what you did? and How can we help you to achieve success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `pygame.time.set_timer()` and pygames event mechanics since you already likely have an event processing loop in your game. See the set_timer docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer).

You do something like this:

```
pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 10000)
```

to start the a 10 second timer that will trigger a pygame.USEREVENT when it goes off. You would watch for that event in the event loop by adding a test like this:

```
if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
    # Countdown expired
```

I doubt that you require it, but if you need multiple timers and need to be able to tell them apart, you can create an event with an attribute that you can set to different values to track them. Something like this:

```
my_event = pygame.event.Event(pygame.USEREVENT, {"tracker": "gameover"})
pygame.time.set_timer(my_event , 2000)
```

[edit]

For other events you just create more of them and change what is set in the "tracker", like this:

```
my_other_event = pygame.event.Event(pygame.USEREVENT, {"tracker": "something_else"})
```

Then in your event loop you look for them. Something like this:

```
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            
            ...

            # You found your event. Do something about it
            if event == my_event:
                ...

            # You found your other event. Do something about it
            if event == my_other_event:
                ...
```

Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good way of doing it.

Comment: @Glenn Mackintosh I know I am asking after 2 years but can you please explain the downer part of myevent = pygame.event.Event etc. as I really need multiple timers. I couldn't understand how should I give different values as you said?

Comment: @ROOPAMBER Not sure what you meant by "downer part", but I added an edit to clarify how you would pick up and do something with the event you defined. Hope this helps. Each event you need should have a different string defined in its "tracker" in place of the "gameover" and be with a different event name instead of my_event.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use the time module (click [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) for the docs).
Here's a program that would print "I'm a replacement for whatever you do in pygame!" until 5 seconds since the start has passed

```py
import time
start = time.time()
seconds = 5
while not time.time() >= start + seconds:
    print("I'm a replacement for whatever you do in pygame!")
print(str(seconds)," seconds is up!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the start time from the [function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) `pygame.time.get_ticks()`.  This gives you the current time (since pygame started) in milliseconds. Store this somewhere.

```
MAX_EVADE_TIME    = 10000   # milliseconds
player_start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

Then during the main loop, continually look at the time, and work out if the limit has passed.

```
while not exiting:

    ...

    time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # is the time limit used-up?
    if ( time_now > player_start_time + MAX_EVADE_TIME ):
        doGameOver()  # or whtever
```