# Doing something after a period of time: Pygame

Tags: python, timer, pygame

I wanted to do something after a period of time. On stack overflow I found a question that helps solve that, [(Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100418/pygame-how-to-wait-a-certain-amount-of-time-to-do-something-after-a-method-has?noredirect=1&lq=1) but when I run the program the code works, however it goes away after a millisecond. Whereas I want it to stay there after the amount of time I want it to wait. In this case for a test run I am blitting some text onto the screen. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
# Importing the modules module.

pygame.init()
# Initializes Pygame

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
# Sets the screen to pygame looks and not normal python looks.

pygame.display.set_caption("Test Run")
# Changes the title

# Heading
headingfont = pygame.font.Font('Bouncy-PERSONAL_USE_ONLY.otf', 45)
headingX = 230
headingY = 10

class Other():
    def show_heading():
        Heading = headingfont.render("Health Run!", True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(Heading, (headingX, headingY))


pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT, 100)

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
                Other.show_heading()

    #Update Display
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw the text permanently, you need to draw it in the application loop. Set a Boolean variable "draw_text" when the timer event occurs. Draw the text depending on `draw_text` in the application loop:

```py
draw_text = False

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            draw_text = True

    if draw_text:
        Other.show_heading()

    #Update Display
    pygame.display.update()
```

For more information about timers and timer events, see [Spawning multiple instances of the same object concurrently in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62112754/spawning-multiple-instances-of-the-same-object-concurrently-in-python/62112894#62112894), [How can I show explosion image when collision happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64305426/how-can-i-show-explosion-image-when-collision-happens/64305746#64305746) or [Adding a particle effect to my clicker game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64793618/adding-a-particle-effect-to-my-clicker-game/64794954#64794954) and many more.

Comment: @SantaClaus make sure to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark

Comment: Yeah, I was going to do that right after I got the problem solved but stack told me to wait 10 minutes before checking it. I did it now though. Thanks for all the support btw!